# How to specify in Grunt.js that the destination folder path is the same as Gruntfile.js?

Tags: syntax, gruntjs

**Problem:** I want to configure a grunt module named [Grunt Markdown](https://github.com/treasonx/grunt-markdown), and part of the configuration requires me to provide a path for the destination file. I don't know how to tell Grunt that I want the destination file to output to the same level as the Gruntfile.js file.

**Info:** I believe that file paths are relative to Gruntfile.js, and I looked at [the documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) to help me understand the syntax. Below you will find a working sample of my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 // Project configuration.
 grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
uglify: {
  build: {
    src: ['js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js','js/jquery.ui.js','js/jquery.iosslider.js','js/jquery.isotope.min.js','js/jquery-css-transform.js','js/jquery-rotate.js','js/browserdetect.js','js/mainactions.js','js/min/gsapi.min.js','js/blurobjs.js','library/scripts/vallenato.js','js/soilsextension_custom.js'],
    dest: 'js/min/master.min.js'
  }
},
sass: {                              // Task
dist: {                            // Target
  options: {                       // Target options
    style: 'compressed'
  },
  files: {                         // Dictionary of files
    'css/main-child/main-child.css': 'css/main-child/main-child.scss',      // 'destination': 'source'
    'css/mobile-child/mobile-child.css': 'css/mobile-child/mobile-child.scss'
  }
}
},
concat: {
options: {
  separator: ' ',
},
dist: {
  src: ['css/main-child/main-child.css', 'css/mobile-child/mobile-child.css'],
  dest: 'css/master-child/master-child.css',
},
 },
markdown:{
all:{
  files:[
    {
      expand:true,
      src:'md/*.md',
      dest:
    }
  ]
}
},
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: ['js/*.js'],
    tasks: ['uglify'],
    options: {
      livereload: true,
    },
  },
  css: {
    files: '**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass','concat'],
    options: {
      livereload: true,
    },

  }
},

imagemin: {                          // Task
    dynamic: {                         // Another target
      files: [{
        expand: true,                  // Enable dynamic expansion
        cwd: 'images/',                   // Src matches are relative to this path
        src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],   // Actual patterns to match
        dest: 'dist/'                  // Destination path prefix
      }]
    }
  }

 });
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
grunt.log.writeln(target + ': ' + filepath + ' has ' + action);
});

// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-markdown');


// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['imagemin']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['markdown']);

};
```

**Question:** What is the syntax necessary to tell Grunt that my destination path is at the root of the project, and what syntax rules does this follow (so that I may reference them later if needed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
markdown: {
  all: {
    files:[
      {
        expand:true,
        src: 'md/*.md',
        dest: './'          
      }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

markdown: {
      all: {
        files:[
          {
            expand:true,
            src: 'md/*.md',
            flatten: true
          }
        ]
     }

Use `flatten` to strip the directory structure.

Thanks